# tabpanel tab onclick method

Tags: visualforce, tab, tabpanel

I want to change value of variable when user clicks on respective tab.

```
<apex:tabPanel switchType="client" value="{!currentTab}" id="theTabPanel">
   <apex:tab label="Step1: " name="one" id="tabOne">  
   </apex:tab>
   <apex:tab label="Step2: " name="two" id="tabTwo">  
   </apex:tab>
   <apex:tab label="Step3: " name="three" id="tabThree">  
   </apex:tab>
</apex:tabPanel>
```

If user clicks on step2 tab then `currentTab=two`.

Answer (score 4):

I would try to use the "dummy" action function with a parameter, that is assigned to the apex variable. Then use the `ontabenter` attribute that triggers the action function if the user enters the current tab and sends the parameter to the variable:

```
<apex:tabPanel switchType="client" value="{!currentTab}" id="theTabPanel">
   <apex:tab label="Step1: " name="one" id="tabOne" ontabenter="changeValue('one');">  
   </apex:tab>
   <apex:tab label="Step2: " name="two" id="tabTwo" ontabenter="changeValue('two');">  
   </apex:tab>
   <apex:tab label="Step3: " name="three" id="tabThree" ontabenter="changeValue('three');">  
   </apex:tab>
</apex:tabPanel>


<apex:actionFunction name="changeValue" reRender="none">
    <apex:param name="p1" value="" assignTo="{!currentTab}" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```